A real root of a cubic equation for a stationary point
Let us consider the quartic polynomial in $x$
\begin{equation} 
       F(x) = (2 a p +2)x^4+ (6a(1-a)p^2+(6-12a)p-6)x^3   
      + p(2(a-2)(a-1)a p^2 + 3(5a^2-9a+2)p +12a-18)x^2 
    - p^2 ((a-2)(4a^2 - 7a +1)p +9a^2-25a+18)x    + (a-2)(a-1)(2a-3)p^3,         (0)
\end{equation}
where $0< a < 2$ and $p > 0$. We are interested in stationary points of  the function $F(x)$  which obey the cubic equation
\begin{equation} 
        F'(x) =  4(2 a p +2)x^3+ 3(6a(1-a)p^2+(6-12a)p-6)x^2  
       + 2p(2(a-2)(a-1)a p^2 + 3(5a^2-9a+2)p +12a-18)x   
    - p^2 ((a-2)(4a^2 - 7a +1)p +9a^2-25a+18) = 0. (1)
         \end{equation}
It is necessary to prove that in the interval $(1, + \infty)$ there no
two different stationary points of $F(x)$ obeying equation (1).
The numerical analysis supports this statetment. Moreover,
the cubic equation (1) has only one root in  the interval $(1, + \infty)$
if and only if
\begin{equation} 
         F'(1) = (p+1)[(a-2)(3a -1)p^2 - 4(a+2)p - 10] < 0.
 \end{equation}
This takes place, for instance, for $1/3 < a < 2$ and all $p > 0$.

What do you exactly mean here by a point  of extremum ?  A point  $x_0$ that is either a local minimum point or a local maximum point?  (Which here means $F’(x_0)=0$,  and  either $F’’(x_0)\neq0$ or  $F’’(x_0)=F’’’(x_0)=0$, I guess)

I am sorry. I have edited the Question:   "extremum point(s)"' is replaced by  "stationary point(s)".

Ok so it's all about the zeros of the cubic G:=F' (and we may forget about F) ?

Yes.  it's all about the zeros of the cubic G:=F'  .

Here is a way, as noted, if $F'(1)<0$ we find one root in $(1,+\infty)$ (proved later).
Assume $F'(1)\ge 0$, so necessarily $0<a<\dfrac{1}{3}$, for $[(2-a)(3a -1)p^2+4(a+2)p+10]\le 0$, $p$ should be outside of its roots, that is $$p\ge \dfrac{4(a+2)+\sqrt{136a^2-216a+144}}{2(1-3a)(2-a)}$$. It is not hard to prove that the last root is increasing in $a$ for $a\in (0,\frac{1}{3})$ (for example, proving $\dfrac{\sqrt{136a^2-216a+144}}{2(1-3a)}$ is increasing...). In case $a=0$,  $p\ge 5$. Now we want to prove that for $x\ge 1$, $F''(x)\ge 0$, this implies the initial claim in question.
$$F''(x)=12(2 a p +2)x^2+ 6(6a(1-a)p^2+(6-12a)p-6)x  
       + 2p(2(a-2)(a-1)a p^2 + 3(5a^2-9a+2)p +12a-18)\ge 0.$$
Since $x\ge 1$, for some fixed $x$  it is almost straight that the expression is increasing in $p$, (for example, rearranging the  terms and taking  $24apx^2+36a(1-a)p^2+36p-72ap+6p^2(5a^2-9a+2)+24ap-36p$ which is increasing in $p$, $p\ge 5$ ...).
Finally, for $p=5$ and $0<a<\frac{1}{3}$ everything can be proved to be positive, which completes the proof.
The other case can be proved as follows, if $F'(0)\ge 0$ and $F'(1)<0$ then from the degree of the polynomial there should be one negative root, one in $[0;1)$ and one in $(1;+\infty)$. Otherwise consider $F'(0)<0$ (product of the roots is positive), the only case to consider is when $F'$ has three roots on $(1;+\infty)$. So
assume $F'(1)<0$ and there is two extremums to $F'$ on $(1;+\infty)$:
Case $1\le a<2$: We prove that $F''(1)<0$, this implies that one extremum of $F'$ is on $(-\infty;1)$ a contradiction: $$F''(1)=-24ap-12+36ap^2(1-a)+4ap^3(a-2)(a-1)+6p^2(5a^2-9a+2).$$
This can be proved decreasing in $p$ and for $p=0$ it is negative.
Case $0<a<1$: We take the sum of the roots of $F''(x)$ and prove it is less than $2$, that is $$\dfrac{-6(6a(1-a)p^2+(6-12a)p-6)}{12(2ap+2)}<2$$
a contradiction.

Dear Toni, thank you so much! You have solved a half of the problem for the case  i) $F'(1) \geq 0$ by proving that there are no roots of the cubic equation  satisfying $x > 1$ for this case. But the case ii)  $F'(1) < 0$  should be also considered in detail, since the last paragraph of my text is just an observation coming from numerical analysis, no more. Indeed, in the second case due to  $F'(1) < 0$ and   $F'(+ \infty) = + \infty$  there should exist at least one real root obeying  $x > 1$.  But a priori there may two roots or three. So, the uniqueness of such root should be proved.

Yes indeed, i missed that, i hope this is now proved. Ty.

Thank a lot! I was close to proof of the second part, and planed to correct slightly the first one.

Dear Toni, the formula after the phrase "rearranging the terms and taking" should be corrected since in second, third and fourth terms the multiplier $x$ is missing.

@Vladimir if i remember this is sufficient i just omitted some terms since $x\ge 1$ etc

Here I present another proof of the Proposition under consideration (called here as Lemma)  which has common points with previous Toni's proof.
Lemma. Let us consider the  function
$$F' = 4(2ap+2)x^3+3(6(1-a)ap^2+(6-12a)p-6)x^2+ $$ $$ 
     2p(2(a-2)(a-1)ap^2+3(5a^2-9a+2)p+12a-18)x  $$ $$ 
           - p^2((a-2)(4a^2-7a+1)p+9a^2-25a+18). \quad (1) $$
Here $0 < a < 2$ and $p > 0$.
Then, the function $F'(x)$ has no more than one root in the interval $(1, + \infty)$.
Moreover, it has one root if
$$(a) \  F'(1) = (p+1)[(a-2)(3a-1)p^2 - 4(a+2)p -10] < 0 $$
and no roots if
$$(b)  \ F'(1) \geq 0. $$
Proof. First, we consider the  case (b), i. e. when
$$(2 - a)(3a-1)p^2 + 4(a+2)p + 10  \leq 0. \quad  (2)$$
This relation implies
$$0 < a < 1/3    $$
since otherwise (for  $1/3 \leq a < 2$) the left hand side in (2) is positive.
Due to (2) or
$$(2 - a)(1 - 3a)p^2 - 4(a+2)p - 10  \geq 0. \qquad     (3a) $$
we get
$$p \geq  p(a) \equiv \frac{4(a +2) + \sqrt{16(a+2)^2 + 40(2 - a)(1 - 3a)}}{2(1-3a)(2-a)}.    \quad (4)$$
The function $p(a)$ is monotonically increasing in interval
$(0,1/3)$ since
$$ \frac{ \sqrt{16(a+2)^2 + 40(2 - a)(1 - 3a)}}{(1-3a)} = $$ $$ 
\sqrt{16(a+2)^2 (1-3a)^{-2}  + 40(2 - a)(1 - 3a)^{-1}} $$
is monotonically increasing in  $a \in (0,1/3)$.
We note that due to the limit $p(+0) = 5$ we obtain
$$ p(a) > 5, \qquad (5a)$$
for all $a$ belonging to $(0,1/3)$.
Now we prove that in case (b)
$$F''(x) = 12(2ap+2)x^2+6(6(1-a)ap^2+(6-12a)p-6)x+ $$ $$ 
     2p(2(a-2)(a-1)ap^2+3(5a^2-9a+2)p+12a-18) > 0  \quad (5)$$
for all $x > 1$, $0 < a < 1/3$ and $p \geq p(a)$,  implying
$$F'(x) > 0  \quad   (6)$$
for all $x > 1$, $0 < a < 1/3$, $p \geq p(a)$, which proves
``one half'' of the Lemma for the case (b).
In order to prove inequality (5) it is sufficient to prove two inequalities
$$V = 6(1-a)ap^2+(6-12a)p-6 > 0, \qquad  (6V)$$
and
$$Z = 2(a-2)(a-1)ap^2+3(5a^2-9a+2)p+12a-18 > 0 \quad (6Z)$$
for all $x > 1$, $0 < a < 1/3$, $p \geq p(a)$.
Plugging the  bound
$$p^2 \geq \frac{(4(a+2)p + 10)}{(2 - a)(1 - 3a)},$$
following from  (3a), into relation for $V$ we obtain
$$V \geq V_b \equiv  \frac{6(1-a)a (4(a+2)p + 10)}{(2 - a)(1 - 3a)}
  (6-12a)p-6 $$
$$=   \frac{6(-10a^3p+13a^2p-3ap+2p-13a^2+17a-2)}{(2-a)(1 -3a)}, 
  \qquad             (7V) $$
and
$$Z \geq Z_b \equiv 
\frac{2(a-2)(a-1)a(4(a+2)p + 10)}{(2 - a)(1 - 3a)}  $$ $$ 
+3(5a^2-9a+2)p  +12a-18  $$ $$ 
= \frac{-53a^3p+88a^2p-29ap+6p-56a^2+86a-18}{1-3a}. \quad (7Z)$$
In order to prove the inequalities (6V) and (6Z) one needs
(due to (7V) and (7Z))
to prove
$$v = (-10a^3+13a^2-3a+2)p-13a^2+17a-2 > 0 \qquad (8v) $$
and
$$z = (-53a^3 + 88a^2 - 29a + 6)p - 56a^2 + 86a - 18 > 0, \quad (8z)$$
for all $0 < a < 1/3$ and $p \geq p(a)$.
The first bound can be readily proved. Indeed,  for the bracket in
(8v) we have
$$(-10a^3+13a^2-3a+2) >  -10 \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3
 - 3 \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) +2 =\frac{17}{27}$$
and hence (using (5a): $ p(a) > 5 $) we get
$$   v   > \frac{17}{27}5 - \frac{13}{9} - 2 = \frac{5}{27} > 0 \quad  (9v)$$
Now we prove the second bound (8z). For the bracket in
(8z) we use the following inequality
$$z_1(a) = (-53a^3 + 88a^2 - 29a + 6) >  3 > 0, \qquad (9z1)$$
for all $0 < a < 1/3$. This can be readily obtained from graphical analysis
of the function  $z_1(a)$ on interval $(0,1/3)$.
This function reaches a minimum at the point
$$a_{min} = -(\sqrt{3133}-88)/159 \approx 0.2014 \quad   (10a)$$
(which could be obtained from quadratic equation $\frac{dz_1(a)}{da} = 0$)
with the value
$$z_1(a_{min}) = \frac{600698 - 2(3133)^{3/2}}{75843}           
       \approx 3.296 >  3. \quad          (10z1)$$
Since  $z_1(a) > 0$, we obtain  for $p \geq p(a)$
$$z = (-53a^3+88a^2-29a+6)p-56a^2+86a-18 $$,
$$ \geq z_b (a) = (-53a^3 + 88a^2-29a+6) p(a) 
 $$ $$   -56a^2+86a-18 > 12. \quad (11z) $$
The last bound (11z) just follows from the graphical analysis of the function
$z_b (a)$ on the interval (0, 1/3). This function is monotonically increasing
from $(12_{+0})$ to $+ \infty$.  Thus, relation (8z) is proved and hence
the part (b) of the Lemma is also proved.
Now we consider the  case (a) $F'(1) < 0$. Here we get two subcases
$$(a1)  \  \ 1/3 \leq  a < 2, \quad  p > 0,   \qquad    (12a1)$$
and
$$(a2)   \  \ 0 < a < 1/3,  \qquad   0 < p < p(a), \qquad  (12a2)$$
where   $ p(a)$ is defined in (4).
Since  $F'(1) < 0$ and $F'(+\infty) = + \infty$,
then due to Intermediate Value Theorem  for all $a$  and  $p$ from  (12a1) and (12a2)
there exists at least one root $x_{*}$ of the cubic polynomial  $F'(x)$  in the interval
$(1, + \infty)$, i.e.
$$F'(x_{*})  = 0,   \qquad  x_{*} > 1.   \qquad     (13)$$
Let us suppose that for some $a$ and $p$ there exists another root   $x_{**} \neq x_{*}$,
i.e. $F'(x_{**})  = 0$. Without loss of generality we put    $x_{*}  < x_{**}$.
An elementary graphical analysis   leads us to three variants for our  cubic polynomial  $F'(x)$:
$$ i)   F''(x_{*})  = 0,  \quad   F''(x_{**})  > 0, $$
$$ii)   F''(x_{*})  > 0,   \quad   F''(x_{**})  = 0,$$
$$iii)  F''(x_{*})  > 0,  \quad    F''(x_{**})  < 0,  
\quad F''(x_{***})  > 0, \quad  (14)$$
where   $x_{***}$ is the third root: $F'(x_{***})  = 0$,  obeying (without loss of generality) $x_{***} > x_{**} $.
By Rolle's theorem we find that in all three cases
there exist two different roots $x_1$, $x_2$   of  quadratic polynomial
$$ H = F''(x)   = 0,  \qquad (15) $$
(see (5)), which satisfy $x_1 \neq x_2$ and
$$F''(x_1) = F''(x_2) = 0. \qquad  (16) $$
By making the redefinition of our variable: $y = x - 1$, we rewrite the  quadratic
equation  (15) as
$$H = H(y) = 24(ap+1)y^2+ 12(3a(1-a)p^2+(3-2a)p+1)y $$
$$  +(4(a - 1)(a - 2)ap^3+ 6(-a^2 - 3a +2)p^2 -24ap -12 = 0. \quad  (17)$$
This quadratic polynomial H(y) should have two different  positive roots
$y_1 = x_1 - 1 >0$ and $y_2 = x_2 - 1 > 0$. Due to Vieta's formulas and  $ ap+1 >0$
we obtain the following inequalities:
$$3a(1-a)p^2+(3-2a)p+1 <  0,  \qquad   (18B)$$
$$4(a - 1)(a - 2)ap^3+ 6(-a^2- 3a+2)p^2 -24ap-12 > 0. \quad (18C)$$
Due to (18B)  we get
$$1 < a < 2. \qquad       (19)$$
It can be readily seen that for this values of  $a$  all coefficients
of the cubic polynomial in the left hand side of  (18C) are negative and
hence the inequality (18C) is not satisfied for all $p > 0$ and $1 < a < 2$.
Thus,  in case (a)   we have only one root of cubic polynomial
$F'(x)$ belonging to $(1, + \infty)$. This finishes the proof of the Lemma.

During the process of compiling the Latex file, a problem arose that I could not solve. I will be grateful if somebody will help me. The trouble occurs for equation (15).

Are you familiar with the formtting sandbox, https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/55/formatting-sandbox – I pasted your two lines of code into an answer there, and it looked fine to me.

Thanks! For me it is also looking fine. The compiling the Latex file on my PC was successful.

You might also look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5024#5024

Thanks! The problem is solved.
